# Conditional IN from DynamoDb not working on java

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am working with `DynamoDB` with `Spring Boot 2.1`, and I'm facing an error when I need o user the clause `IN` during the conditional evaluation. Even with lines that fulfill the requirements, the query result is empty.

How can I return the lines from the table after explicit the result within the `IN` clause ?

```
public class DynamoRepository {

    private final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    
    public Optional<List<USER>> query(String id) {
        Map<String, String> ean = new HashMap<>();
        ean.put("#status", "status");

        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
        eav.put(":id", new AttributeValue().withS(documento));

        DynamoDBQueryExpression<USER> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<USER>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :id")
            .withFilterExpression("#status in (ACTIVE, PENDING)")
            .withExpressionAttributeNames(ean)
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

        List<USER> query = dynamoDBMapper.query(USER.class, queryExpression);

        return query.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(query);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking a while, my solution was to define the status' values as Expression Attribute Values like the code below

```
public class DynamoRepository {

    private final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    
    public Optional<List<USER>> query(String id) {
        Map<String, String> ean = new HashMap<>();
        ean.put("#status", "status");

        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
        eav.put(":id", new AttributeValue().withS(documento));
        eav.put(":active", new AttributeValue().withS("ACTIVE"));
        eav.put(":pending", new AttributeValue().withS("PENDING"));

        DynamoDBQueryExpression<USER> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<USER>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :id")
            .withFilterExpression("#status in (:active, :pending)")
            .withExpressionAttributeNames(ean)
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

        List<USER> query = dynamoDBMapper.query(USER.class, queryExpression);

        return query.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(query);
    }

}
```